# Swap in verilog HDL using model sim

Tags: sorting

I have wrote the code to process the elements by reading from the txt file. I tried to swap values... but is's not working. Pls help me out.

begin

```
$display("rdata");
for (i=0; i<5; i=i+1)
for (j=i+1; j<6; j=j+1)
if(data[i]<data[j])
k=data[i];
data[i]=data[j];
data[j]=k;
$display("%h",data[i]);
fp1=$fopen("vectors2.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the scope of if condition. Try this:

```
$display("rdata");
for (i=0; i<5; i=i+1)
    for (j=i+1; j<6; j=j+1)
        if(data[i]<data[j])
        {
            k=data[i];
            data[i]=data[j];
            data[j]=k;
        }
$display("%h",data[i]);
fp1=$fopen("vectors2.txt");
```